# How to read the first column of a CSV file with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to read a CSV file with powershell.

I currently do the following:

```
#Reading CSV
$stats = Import-Csv -Path $counterFile -Delimiter $separator
```

And now I need to extract the column values in differents objects.

I've seen that I should be able to access it like this:

```
$stats.ColumnHeader
```

The issue is that this column contains dates, and a genius decided that the header of this column would be the timezone of the computer in a weird format.

So how can I read the first column without "knowing" the header text and without modifying the other columns headers?

Is there a way to access this column through indexes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject) has a few hidden properties:

```
$Stats |Get-Member -Force

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
pstypenames CodeProperty System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] pstypenames{get=PSTypeNames;}
psadapted   MemberSet    psadapted {ToString, GetType, Equals, GetHashCode}
psbase      MemberSet    psbase {ToString, GetType, Equals, GetHashCode}
psextended  MemberSet    psextended {Id, Name, Country, EMail, Age, ReportsTo}
psobject    MemberSet    psobject {BaseObject, Members, Properties, Methods, ImmediateBaseObject, TypeNames, get_BaseObject, get_Members, get_Properties, get_Methods, get_ImmediateBaseObject, get_TypeNames, ToString, Copy, CompareTo, Equals, GetHash…
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
...         NoteProperty ...
```

Where the `PSObject` property contains a `Properties` property containing child properties along with the `Name` and the `Value` of each `$Stats` property.
In other words, to find out the name of the first `$Stats[0]` property (aka first column), you can do:

```
$Stats[0].PSObject.Properties.Name[0]
ColumnHeader
```

And to retrieve all the values of that column:

```
$ColumnName = $Stats[0].PSObject.Properties.Name[0]
$Stats.$ColumnName
```

Or:

```
$Stats.($Stats[0].PSObject.Properties.Name[0])
```

Comment: hi @iRon , if I'm trying to access each value; during the looping process from a CSV file; how can I do that. I put in the above and it lists out as you have suggested all Item numbers for me. My code is:-
$check_date = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy"
$csv = Import-Csv E:\Projects_PROD\Inventoryexp\stores_TEST.csv
ForEach($line in $csv)
{$ColumnName = $csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name[0]
$MailSubject = "AutoShip Forecast Report - "+$csv.$ColumnName+" - "+$check_date
}
## and my file contains 1 column ITEM and then item no example like A230,B600, etc.

Comment: Okay I posted question centric to my question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73226176/powershell-reading-specific-columns-each-value-during-for-loop