# Powershell Reading specific column's each value during FOR loop

Tags: powershell

Already saw this url: [How to read the first column of a CSV file with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089645/how-to-read-the-first-column-of-a-csv-file-with-powershell)
That said what I'm trying to accomplish is from a CSV file that contains 2 columns. I need to read the first column's value and mail to second column
CSV Example

| Item | Email |
| --- | --- |
| A300 | bob@gg.com |
| B600 | loco@dd.com |

```
$check_date = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy"
$csv = Import-Csv C:\stores_TEST.csv
ForEach($line in $csv)
{$ColumnName = $csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name[0]
$MailSubject = "Report - "+$csv.$ColumnName+" - "+$check_date
}
```

I can either get the ITEM to show up; example Report - 2030 2098 2134 2247 2337 3243 7126 2140
OR in try 2 I can get  Report - ITEM - 08-03-2022 .
But I want  Report - A300 - 08-03-2022.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Do you mean your csv file is without headers? The example shows headers `Item` and `Email` though.. so if it has these, why the need for code to get the columnnames if they are already known? I also suggest you change `$csv.$ColumnName` to `$line.$ColumnName`, since that is the name of the iterating variable you use.

Comment: Sorry - I misread the question and have reopened it (note that you must `@`-mention me in order to be actively notified of follow-up comments). Good catch, @Theo.